# Containerized Spring Boot web app on Azure app service has health check failing due to 302 error

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-web-app-service, containers

I have a containerized Java Spring Boot web app deployed using Azure App Service. I have enabled Actuator Health Check endpoint which is accessible at https:///actuator/health.

I enabled Health Check for the service and it cribs that 'Your app is unhealthy'. Following statements keep on appearing in the log:

```
2021-07-26T06:52:44.592883929Z 172.16.0.1 - [26/Jul/2021:06:52:44 +0000] GET HTTP/1.1 "GET /actuator/health HTTP/1.1" 302 154 0.000 "-" "HealthCheck/1.0" "-"

2021-07-26T06:52:45.436822668Z 172.16.0.1 - [26/Jul/2021:06:52:45 +0000] GET HTTP/1.1 "GET /actuator/health HTTP/1.1" 302 154 0.000 "-" "ReadyForRequest/1.0 (HealthCheck)" "-"

2021-07-26T06:52:51.107134976Z 172.16.0.1 - [26/Jul/2021:06:52:51 +0000] GET HTTP/1.1 "GET /actuator/health HTTP/1.1" 302 154 0.000 "-" "HealthCheck/1.0" "-"

2021-07-26T06:52:51.124Z WARN  - Container for <instance> site <application-name> is unhealthy, recycling site.
```

I have set 'HTTPS Only' in the TLS/SSL settings as well. When I ran 'Diagnose and solve problems' it didn't give any problems with Health Check.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Healthcheck URL needs to return a success status code (200-299), otherwise App Services will consider it failed. Also, it works only on HTTP, iirc.

If your app has a redirect to https built-in you should make sure to whitelist the Healthcheck user agent so the healthcheck url does not redirect and returns a success status code instead.